# Run a serial connection over SSH

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, ssh-tunneling, serial-port, serial-console

EDIT: After some advice here and additional investigation here, the situation is now as follows:

I have a serial device that takes input in batches of four bytes and outputs responses in batches of four or eight bytes.

0x01010000 is the first command we ever want to send to our serial device.

I know that 0x01fef40b0201080b is the correct output. If I run

`echo -n -e "\x01\x01\x00\x00" | socat - /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200 > temp && hexdump temp`

after connecting the serial device I always get

`0000000 01fe f40b 0201 080b`

as output (the first batch of zeros is from `hexdump`), so everything works.

However, if I run

`socat -,raw /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200`

in one terminal on the Raspberry Pi directly, then

`echo -n -e "\x01\x01\x00\x00" | socat - /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200 > temp && hexdump temp`

in another terminal (again on the Raspberry Pi directly, so no SSH potentially breaking things here!) does not output

`0000000 01fe f40b 0201 080b`

anymore. Instead, I either

- get no output
- get something like `0000000 01fe 0002` or `0000000 0b02 0008` or `0000000 01fe 08f4` or ... (so always wrong and shorter than expected)
- get something like `0000000 01fe 0b02 0008` (same, but three bytes this time)
- or get something similar that is too short and wrong.

So it seems that when I just launch `socat -,raw /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200`, without sending anything over to the serial device (at least explicitly), something breaks and I get wrong outputs, as if something had been sent that caused some sort of offset (which is why the responses become too short suddenly).

However, I've run `strace socat -,raw /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200` and cannot find any `write` commands in the output, so I don't know what could be going on.

So it seems like something about `socat` breaks things but I don't know what it could be. And it seems to be purely `socat`, without any involvement of the Windows program or SSH whatsoever.

EDIT 2: I've just found if I run `socat` without feeding it any input but with `strace` such that it exits instead of staying open, e.g.

`strace socat -,raw /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200 > strace3`

then when I run

`echo -n -e "\x01\x01\x00\x00" | socat - /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0,b19200 > temp && hexdump temp`

again, all seems to be working fine. So it seems that when `socat` does not break things, it is not thanks to feeding it input but because it terminates instead of staying open.

---

Consider the following scenario:

1. We have a Windows PC (don't worry, it's the smallest part of the equation, but still an important detail as you will see).
2. We have a serial device.
3. We have a Raspberry Pi running some fairly up-to-date Raspbian.

We want a program on the Windows PC to connect to the serial device via SSH, which is to say, it's supposed to send the same data via SSH as if the device was connected via COM, and it's supposed to receive the same data via SSH as if the device was connected via COM.

My idea for a solution involved the Raspberry Pi. The serial device is connected to the Raspberry Pi. On the Raspberry Pi the user we SSH as has no visible prompt and has a login bash script that directly launches a *screen* terminal to the serial port, such that this serial terminal is launched directly upon connection with no console output beforehand. This way, or so I thought, I could let the SSH connection act as a direct tunnel to the serial device.

However, it turns out that when I send a command to the serial device under this configuration, what I get in return is not what I expect.

My questions now are:

1. Could this fail because SSH expects text characters no matter what, and cannot handle e.g. a byte string like **0x0000** as input? I don't know if this is true, it's just something that I thought about.
2. I run SSH on the Windows machine with the **-tt** flag. I do this because otherwise I cannot pipe stdin and stdout from the ssh process and the process of my program in such a way that I can read from ssh's stdout and write into its stdin. Could it be that -tt maybe breaks things?
3. Or is my entire idea of how to do all this just plain wrong from the outset?

Keep in mind that I cannot resort to solutions like using *remserial* for the tunneling because the PC runs on Windows (this is why that detail was important).

Thank you for taking your time to read this. Please let me know if I should post this somewhere else.

Comment: ssh has no issues with NUL characters. Using `screen` is probably overkill, I would reach for the swiss army knife of `socat`. This would eliminate the need to allocate ptys and hence the -tt flag. Are you thinking of using `screen` to keep the connection to the serial device open across multiple ssh calls, or just as a way to open the serial device? Put it another way, once you have this set up what would you typically hope the program on the windows machine to do - is it say a python script that speaks the ssh protocol?

Comment: I was using `screen` only to open the serial device, in fact, I close the device whenever the SSH connection closes or exits.

Comment: The program on the Windows machine uses ssh transparently by just creating an ssh process and writing into a file handle that is piped to its stdin. It does not speak the ssh protocol in any way, that is left to the ssh binary.

Comment: If you want to connect real serial programs to real serial devices you need a channel able to pass serial ioctls (to set DTR, etc). That's the rub, and `socat`, etc won't cut it. If you find a solution for that (eg. [rfc2217](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2217), [ser2net](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ser2net) server on linux, ?? on windows), tunnelling it through any kind of ssh forwarding is no big deal. See also this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498332/virtual-tty-client-for-network-telnet-rfc2217-server), though that's about a rfc2217 _client_ running on linux).

Comment: socat can do a reasonable number of the ioctls, set the baud rate, parity etc. It doesn't have a remote channel to do it on, but there is no indication that this is a requirement, the OP can just do something like `ssh pi socat -,raw /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,b19200`

Comment: I'd use `cu`: `cu -l /dev/ttyS0 -s 19200`

Comment: I've tried ```socat``` and ```cu```, unfortunately I still get unexpected data with ```socat```. ```cu``` works sometimes but is extremely inconsistent. I have not yet figured out why or if I can fix it. Maybe this is why its manpage includes the rather amusing remark under BUGS that "[t]his program does not work very well".

Comment: @Adrian "unfortunately I still get unexpected data with socat" doesn't give us much information to help us debug the issue.  Once the endpoints are set up socat is doing almost the simplest thing imaginable, namely copying the data between the two endpoints. The fact that you get unexpected results with screen, socat and cu suggests that your expectations may be wrong. If you run the socat directly on the pi and so drive the serial device "by hand" does it behave correctly?

Comment: @icarus `socat` cannot pass through _any_ ioctls. It cannot do that, since it doesn't do any protocol able to pass them through. Most serial programs _need_ `TIOCMSET`, `TIOCMIWAIT` in order to control the devices. And yes, they're also used and useful with rs232<->usb adapters. There's also `TCSETS2`/`termios2` which is the only way to set arbitrary speeds on Linux (and the only way to use some devices), which is not supported at all by `socat`/whatever. There's nothing "reasonable" about something that does __not__ work.

Comment: @icarus I have trouble driving the serial device "by hand" via socat because I always get `Inappropriate ioctl for device` when feeding any input into socat via `|`. However, I have also noticed that the "unexpected data" I get with socat is an echo of what I send, but "converted to a string". More specifically, when I send `0x01010000`, at least the first four bytes of what I get in return are `^A^A`, as in `0x5E415E41`.

Comment: If you are piping data into socat then change the `-,raw` to just `-` to stop it trying to set the input stream, which it is expecting to be a tty, into raw mode. So are you sending binary and something is echoing the response. This could be the serial driver or it could be the remote serial device. In general it is better to show the bytes individually rather than packing them into groups of 4 and then we need to worry about byte order. Is the serial deice running some kind of linux?

Comment: Thanks for the advice about removing the `,raw`, I can feed input via `|` now.

I think the echo is caused by the serial driver or by some configuration of socat because there is no echo when connecting to the serial device directly through Windows (as in our original setup). Also I didn't get any echo when using `cu`. The serial device is entirely custom and developed inhouse and I don't think it runs any Linux either but I don't have access to its code so I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: I have found out how to disable the echo via `stty`. When I do that, my setup behaves the same way with `socat` as it used to do with `cu`. This suggests that there may still be a problem somewhere else beyond the tunnelling. I'll investigate.

Comment: The problem seems to be a strange timing issue, when sending and receiving happen too close to each other, I receive incomplete or wrong data. I use `socat -,raw /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,b19200`. What could cause this?

Comment: Timing issues are not unusual with serial communications. The chips doing the sending and receiving are called UARTs and have small buffers. Early ones such as the 8250 only had a single byte buffer but later  ones such as the 16550 had 16 bytes. Since you want to exchange binary data you can't use software flow control, aka XON/XOFF. The correct thing to do is to use extra wires in the serial cable - hardware flow control. I would expect that the Pi would be fast enough to not need hardware flow control. Another thing you can try is `expect` with its send_slow to dribble out the characters.

Comment: The thing is there don't seem to be any timing issues when connecting to the serial device directly instead of using the SSH connection. Also, I notice that when I am being "too fast", I get the "string-ified echo" as a response even though I have disabled the echo and there is no echo when I wait a bit before sending and receiving. What problem could this suggest?

Comment: I just solved the "string-ified echo" problem. Apparently it was caused when my program started sending commands before `.bash_login` had actually finished executing, so it hadn't gotten around to starting `socat` yet and the commands were just written into bash. I can fix this by a one-time sleep of 1s.

Comment: The other problems boil down to the fact that opening socat with `socat -,raw /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,b19200` seems to input something unknown into the terminal on execution of said command, throwing everything off on the serial device. This is not caused by my code but simply by the call of `socat` itself. Interestingly, when I execute `socat` by means of a command that feeds input into it, e.g. `echo "\x01\x01\x00\x00" | socat ...`, there is no problem. What could this be?

Comment: You have far too many moving pieces! The windows machine should be running `ssh user@pi socat -,raw /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,b19200`, and the `.bashrc` file on the pi should probably do nothing if it is being run from ssh, so the first line could be `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. This gets rid of all (hopefully) of the pty and tty allocations.

Comment: Things break when calling `socat` even on the Pi directly, without the Windows PC involved in any way. I can tell by looking at the output of `socat` on the Pi directly and without executing the Windows program, so the Windows program is definitely not involved in this problem. It seems that `socat` makes some sort of input into the serial device when launching that throws everything off.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to reflect what you now know? Please add as much detail as you can. It may be obvious to you by looking at the output of socat directly on the Pi, but remember that we haven't been told what this output is. In one comment you say that using echo to pipe into socat works but in the next you say socat doesn't work. socat is not going to send some sort of input into the serial device.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the question is missing a lot of what I know why and even so I haven't been as clear as I could have. I'll update it right away.

Comment: If you have two `socat` programs running on the Pi at the same time, connected to the same device, and the device sends "Please give me some beer", each character will go pretty much at random to the two socat processes. So one might get "Plaser" and the other "eer giv me some bee". So the trick is not to run two socat processes. You may think in terms of "I send a command and get a response", but each socat is just "copy stuff between the two endpoints". Good to see the details, and that you know about strace. Next hint is use `hexdump -C` if your version of hexdump supports it.

Comment: Another thing you can help with is to put @icarus into messages directed at me, so I get a notification that something has been said to me, rather than me keep looking at this question to see if I can help more.

Comment: @icarus My apologies, I'm new here so I thought you were being notified of my replies all the time. In any case, we've decided to pursue a different solution. Thank you very much for all the assistance you provided, you've been a tremendous help and I would have been forced to give up much sooner without you. :)

Comment: I am aware you are new here, hence my explicit request. Sorry that I couldn't help you get to a solution based on your original plan. If we had got to the stage of me writing up an answer then I would be notified about the comments on that answer. The main thing I hope you learnt for next time is to keep editing the question to add additional information when you learn it, and to remember that what is obvious to you may not be obvious to us. Give exact messages rather than "I get unexpected data". Tell us that you are setting up 2 connections to the device....

Comment: @icarus Thank you for the advice, I'll be sure to keep that in mind for the future.