# Is it possible to use TIOCMBIS with pseudo-terminal?

Tags: linux, tty, pseudoterminal

I have a C program which works with a normal terminal using this code:

```
int dtr_rts = TIOCM_DTR | TIOCM_RTS; /* out-of-band signal */
...
int comfd = open(COM_PORT, O_RDWR);
...
ioctl(comfd, TIOCMBIS, &dtr_rts);
```

Now I need to run this program on a pseudo-terminal. How do I read DTR/RTS on master side? Is DTR/RTS set to `1` or to `0` by default (i.e., on `open()`) on `/dev/pts/X`?

Is `TIOCMGET` ioctl implemented for pseudo-terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. A pseudo terminal has no way to pass through serial ioctls like `TIOCMBIS` or `TIOCSET`.

See also:

[Virtual tty client for network telnet/RFC2217 server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498332/virtual-tty-client-for-network-telnet-rfc2217-server#comment917374_498332)

[Run a serial connection over SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534562/run-a-serial-connection-over-ssh#comment990184_534562)

Comment: I have found a workaround (although slight changes in the program which uses the tty are needed): Those processes are on the same computer (as using a pseudo-terminal implies), so I can use IPC mechanisms for out-of-band signalling. For example, I will create a file in slave and poll it in master after starting slave (this file must be removed before slave is started). [The program sets dtr_rts to 1 only once after it starts when it is ready to accept data.]

Comment: You can also use a `LD_PRELOAD` hack to run unmodified programs, and pass the modem bits by re-purposing some unused termios special character (eg `c_cc[VEOL2]`), and passing the changes using the trick from the 2nd link. I'll add a full example when I have time and a machine where I can build & test.